# Make call to selected contact from default phonebook

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new at android development. I want to create an application which allows user on a button click to open default contact list and make a call to selected contact. Any help will be really appreciated ! Thank you !

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

Place this code in the onClickListner event of a button

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); startActivityForResult(intent, 1);